# Can I boot over symlinks?

Tags: boot, lvm, grub, symlink, fhs

So I have multiple drives in my pc, but because of the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard it is very impractical to store progams and similar on those drives. I personally also just don't like having multiple drives and prefer having one large drive, but because of re-using parts and being broke almost always it just turned out this way.

In windows you can make a spanned partition across multiple drives. You can't boot from it, but windows doesn't have a Filesystem Hierarchy Standard like linux has, so that isn't much of a problem. In linux you can set up an lvm, but, just like windows, it is not adviced to boot from that, but because of the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard I couldn't just simply store my programs on an lvm with a seperate boot partition.

As a solution, I thought that I could maybe make a partition from which I boot, which only contains symlinks to the lvm, where the actual data is stored. I just don't know if that's even possible. I guess that it depends on if the bootloader (grub) can recognise and follow the symlinks, right?

If this is in fact not possible, I could make symlinks for the folders that are not required for/during boot, but I have no idea which folders that are.

Comment: One of the major differences between the *nix and Windows approaches is that the directory structure of a running *nix system can be composed by `mount`ing an arbitrary number of volumes (including LVMs). Yet it looks like you are assuming the full directory hierarchy of a running system needs to be contained in a single storage volume, with the sole exception of symlinked directories. Am I misreading your question?

Comment: I think it is indeed a miscommunication, but that could also be on my side. I am not very familiar with how linux actually works. I am quite a noob.

Comment: No problem, of course. I may be misreading your question. What do you mean by _"because of the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard it is very impractical to store programs and similar on those drives"_? What is scattered across your drives? Free space you'd like to use as a single volume for a newly installed system? Pieces of software that, on a typical *nix system, would be located in the same top level directory (e.g. `/usr`)? Different top level directories (e.g. `/home`)? Something else?

Comment: The way I understand it, if you install a program or library using the terminal, it will automatically install on the drive with your root directory and while you can specify to install it on a different drive, mounted somewhere in your filesystem, it will not have acces to the libraries and such in the main drive, like any other program would. My plan was to make a small partition for the root directory and then make symlinks in the root directory to an lvm with all my drives in it. I would make symlinks for folders like `/usr` and `/home`. I found that I can also use fstab instead of symlink

Comment: When you install a program, its files go to the drive(s) the concerned directories (e.g. `/usr`, `/etc`, `/bin`) are actually located on. It is not necessarily the one that has `/` (the root directory)). See [`man 8 mount`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) for more on this. Yes, `fstab` is a way to tell the system what to mount and where, so it is likely the way to go for you.

Answer (score 1):

The only files you need to be able to access in order to boot a Linux system are the kernel and the initramfs (if you use one; most distributions do). There are two main ways of doing this on current PCs: they can be stored on the EFI system partition (ESP), or in a partition dedicated to `/boot`. The latter is the configuration supported by most distributions.

Everything else can live in a logical volume, or several, built any way you want, over any number of disks (within the limits of the kernel’s `md` subsystem, but they’re high enough not to be a concern). Typically you’d have one volume for `/` and one for `/home`, and perhaps others (`/usr/var`, ...) but you don’t have to.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Unix standard use was to have a (small) boot drive (with `/bin`, `/lib`, `/etc`, `/tmp`, perhaps `/sbin` and very little else), and mount e.g. a drive with `/usr`, another with `/home`, ... on appropiate points. Today's TiB drives make this (mostly) moot... your distribution's installation will probably set up a (small) partition for booting and "the rest of the disk", you still can set up and mount other disk drives (even network filesystems) under that and have it all seen as a (mostly) seamless unit.

Setting this up (or using LVM to create a logical volume spanning several disks, etc) will probably mean installing from scratch.

Comment: Thanks! I've decided to test if I could get a pretty much clean install of kubuntu to boot when I copy the /home, /usr and /snap directories to an lvm made up of two USB drives and then mount those folders on their appropriate places using fstab, but it hasn't been successful at all. When I try to use the /usr on the lvm through fstab, it just boots straight into shell and if I try with any of the other directories, I get weird graphical glitches, where I can move the mouse around, but everything is black and nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Yes, grub can follow symlinks to boot from, i.e. load the kernel and the initial ramdisk.

I know this, because before every significant system change I not only make a backup, but also restore that to another one of my internal or external hard disks, as fallback generations of my system. To avoid having to update grub.cfg on each of them, I just have a set of generic grub menu entries in a file I named `/etc/grub.d/30_otherbootables`. That file refers to symbolic links in each disk's root directory, and booting works:

```
linux   /vmlinuz ...
initrd  /initrd.img ...
```

and in a second menu entry

```
linux   /vmlinuz.old ...
initrd  /initrd.img.old ...
```

My system (Ubuntu) itself creates these symlinks on every update or upgrade, but of course I could do the same myself. They link to the current and previous `bootvmlinuz-version` and `boot/initrd.img-version` that the update chooses to install.

It will be obvious, of course, that the links are relative, and refer to files on the same disks.